# vbscript dictionary adding in loop producing existing key error

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, recordset

I'm simply trying to construct a dictionary of productIDs

```
dim viewableProductIDs : set viewableProductIDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    do while not rsEntry.EOF
        viewableProductIDs.Add rsEntry("ProductID"), true
        rsEntry.MoveNext
    loop
```

rsEntry is a ADODB Recordset and I have made sure, through exhaustive debbug printing, that my query is indeed returning unique productIDs and that the recordset has no duplicates.  Yet someohow, vbscript insists on thinking there are duplicates.  It'll add the first one fine, but after that it errors out on all the rest.  I tried surrounding it with a check for existing key and it someohow thought they all, but the first, existed.  Then in the end I'm left with a dictionary with only one entry in it.

Does anyone have any idea as to why it's doing this?

Comment: Just to make sure, try to execute `SELECT DISTINCT ProductId FROM YourTable`, put its result into rsEntry variable and run your code again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `.Value`:

```
viewableProductIDs.Add rsEntry("ProductID").Value, true
```

**Explanation:**

VBScript has a concept called "default" properties.  For instance, the line

```
someString = rsEntry("ProductID")
```

really is shorthand for

```
someString = rsEntry.Fields.Item("ProductID").Value
```

where `Fields`, `Item`, and `Value` are all the default properties of their respective objects.  The main problem here is in the last step of the chain: the difference between `rsEntry("ProductID")` and `rsEntry("ProductID").Value`.  In the above example, since I didn't use the `Set` keyword, an object reference would be illegal for the right-hand side of the assignment.  Since `rsEntry("ProductID")` evaluates to a `Field` object reference, the interpreter takes the next step and expands the default property of the `Field` object, `Value`.  If I had done

```
Set someObj = rsEntry("ProductID")
```

the interpreter would have set `someObj` to the `Field` object reference.

Now here's the fun part: the `Dictionary` object can use any type of value as its keys.  It's more common to use simple values like strings or numbers, but it's perfectly legal to use arrays or object references.  Since an object reference is legal for the first argument of the `Dictionary.Add` method, the interpreter doesn't bother to expand the default property and simply uses the `Field` object reference as the key.  Since the `Field` object reference doesn't change from record to record, you end up trying to add the same key over and over.  Adding `.Value` makes it explicitly clear to the interpreter that you want the value, not the object.

Comment: Aha, I knew something like this had to be going on.  Thanks, this definitely solved the issue.